# How to pip install packages written in Pipfile without creating virtualenv?

Tags: python, docker, pip, pipfile

I created a package, containing [Pipfile](https://github.com/pypa/pipfile), and I want to test with docker.

I want to install packages written in Pipfile with pip, without creating virutalenv.

```
# (do something to create some-file)
RUN pip install (some-file)
```

How to do?

Comment: Same as using venv, just use your local installation pip.

Comment: Make sure pip is available in your system and then run it directly... Please note that pip will not install the system's dependency for you.

Comment: I want to install packages written in Pipfile

Comment: Pipfile is just a replacement for "requirements.txt". So I think you can use the similar way `RUN pip install -p <name-of-your-pipfile>`.

Comment: Sorry, currently `pip` doesn't support `pipfile` yet. You have to use `pipenv install <package-names>`

Comment: Finally I used `poetry` instead of `pipenv`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually pip should be able to do this itself, at least that's what they say. Currently, that is not yet implemented.

For now, a Pipfile is a TOML file, so you can use a TOML parser to extract the package constraints and emit them in a format that will be recognized by pip. For example, if your Pipfile contains only simple string version specifiers, this little script will write out a `requirements.txt` file that you can then pass to `pip install -r`:

```
import sys
import toml

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    result = toml.load(f)
for package, constraint in result['packages'].items():
    if constraint == '*':
        print(package)
    else:
        print(f'{package} {constraint}')
```

If your Pipfile contains more complicated constructs, you'll have to edit this code to account for them.

---

An alternative that you might consider, which is suitable for a Docker container, is to use `pipenv` to install the packages into the system Python installation and just remove the generated virtual environment afterwards.

```
pipenv install --system
pipenv --rm
```

However, strictly speaking that doesn't achieve your stated goal of doing this without creating a virtualenv.

Comment: I am not sure there is a need to remove the virtual env. It appears that none has been created at this stage.
`No virtualenv has been created for this project yet!`

Comment: Huh, I seem to rememberwhen I tried it a virtualenv was created. Maybe that's changed in a recent version. I'll restet it and try to clarify in an edit.

Answer (score 7):

One of the other answers lead to me to this, but wanted to explicitly call it out, and why it's a useful solution.

Pipenv is useful as it helps you create a virtual environment. This is great on your local dev machine as you will often have many projects, with different dependencies etc.

In CICD, you will be using containers that are often are only spun up for a few minutes to complete part of your CICD pipeline. Since you will spin up a new container each time you run your pipeline, there is no need to create a virtual environment in your container to keep things organised. You can simply install all your dependencies directly to the main OS version of python.

To do this, run the below command in your CICD pipeline:

`pipenv install --system`